# Automatisation pageName in dataLayer based on urls

Tags: javascript, html, url, launch, google-datalayer

I would like to automate the `pageName` of the `dataLayer` push
The pageNames are based on the url.
And my website are on launch

The datalayer puSh are like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    dataLayer.push(
    {
        "site": ".....",
        "pageName": "FR:UU:Intranet:Accueil",
    });
</script>
```

I try to automate with the `window.document.title` but the title are not clean in the html
Do you know how to automate the `pageName` ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: How is the title not "clean" in the html?

Comment: The title are the same on all the page of the website, this is why it's not clean, I mean we can't use it